# Issues fitting gaussian to scatter plot

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm having a lot of trouble fitting this data, particularly getting the fit parameters to match the expected parameters.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 

def gaussian_model(x, a, b, c, d): # add constant d
    return a*np.exp(-(x-b)**2/(2*c**2))+d

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)

mu, cov = curve_fit(gaussian_model, xdata, ydata)
fit_A = mu[0]
fit_B = mu[1]
fit_C = mu[2]
fit_D = mu[3]

fit_y = gaussian_model(xdata, fit_A, fit_B, fit_C, fit_D)
print(mu)
plt.plot(x, fit_y)
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.show()
```

[Here's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmCS4.png)

When I printed the parameters, I got values of -17 for amplitude, 2.6 for mean, -2.5 for standard deviation, and 110 for the base. This is very far off from what I would expect from the scatter plot. Any ideas why?

Also, I'm pretty new to coding, so any advice is helpful! Thanks everyone :)

Edit: figured out what was wrong! Just needed to add some guesses.

Comment: Congrats on figuring out the problem. Now that you've figured out your own solution, could write an answer to your own post and mark it as correct, in case others have the same problem and so this question is marked as solved rather than editing the question with the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer as expected.

This is an alternative method of fitting gaussian.

The process is not iteratif and doesn't requier initial "guessed" values of the parameters to start as in the usual methods.

The result is :

[image]

The method of calculus is shown below :

[image]

The general principle is explained with examples in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . This is a linear regression wrt an integral equation which solution is the gaussian function.

If one want more accurate and/or more specific result according to some specified criteria of fitting, one have to use a software with non-linear regression process. Then one can use the above result as initial values of parameters for a more robust iterative process.